# Three vertices of a rectangle are (-4,5), (-4,2) and (3,2). Plot these points and find the coordinates of the fourth vertex.

Tags: geometry

This question forms part of **Coordinate Geometry**

There are three vertices of a rectangle, namely:

$$A(-4,5), B(-4,2), C(3,2)$$

How would I plot these points and find the coordinates of the fourth vertex? $D(x,y)$

Comment: I tried to add information to the question, as the original question was missing details.

Answer (score 3):

Well, interesting question ;) Anyways, I'll answer it:

Your 4 points of the rectangle are $$A(-4,5), B(-4,2), C(3,2),D(x,y)$$

From inspection, we can see that $A$ and $B$ have the same $x$ value, and it is most likely that this rectangle is not slanted as $B$ and $C$ have the same y value. Let's continue from here:

From point $B$ to point $A$, the $y$ value increased by 3, so we can say that from point $C$ to point $D$ the $y$ value should also increase by 3 units. We can therefore deduce that the $y$ value of $D = (2+3) = 5$. Which also is the $y$ value of point $A$. Now for the $x$ values...

From point $B$ to point $D$ the x value increases by 7, so we can say that the $x$ value should also increase by 7 from point $A$ to point $D$... Therefore the $x$ value of D is $(-4 + 7) = 3$ (Which is the same $x$ value as point $C$

---

Sometimes it is hard to understand how the graph looks by just reading the points, so let's make it graphical:[image]

I hope this helped ;)